# Can't import .OBJ in Blender 2.8

Tags: objects, import, error

I'm having issue with importing an obj into Blender 2.8. I get a red bit of text in the corner about line 145 for the OBJ add-on not working? (Error in picture at bottom right)

[image: Error is at the bottom right]

Comment: Have you been able to open the OBJ file in other software?

Comment: Please post the full error message. If you're on Windows you can show the console through *Windows > Toggle System Console*.

Comment: @rjg This is the full error Progress:  66.67%

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\__init__.py", line 145, in execute
    return import_obj.load(context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\import_obj.py", line 1230, in load
    for data in split_mesh(verts_loc, faces, unique_materials, filepath, SPLIT_OB_OR_GROUP):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\import_obj.py", line 519, in split_mesh

Comment: @OliverWhite There is no error message in your comment? BTW you can edit your question and put the error message there.

Comment: @rjg Sorry about that, pressed enter without knowing that that will submit the comment, also this is the rest of the error: verts_split.append(verts_loc[vert_idx])  # add the vert to the local verts
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That looks like the .obj your trying to import may not be following the specification. There seems to be a reference to a vertex index in the face definition that doesn't exist. Can you share the .obj file?

Comment: @rjg not sure how to do that